# Making Wordpress REST API on my custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am making Wordpress REST API on my custom plugin.

I have added this code on plugin construct

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'api/pay', 'transactions/(?P<category_id>\d+)',array(
    'methods'  => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_latest_posts_by_category'
  ));
});
```

And made function like this.

```
function get_latest_posts_by_category($request) {
  $args = array(
    'category' => $request['transaction_id']
  );

  $response = new WP_REST_Response($args);
  $response->set_status(200);
  return $response;
}
```

But I can't call my rest api.
I have got this error:

```
{
  "code": "rest_no_route",
  "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
  "data": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you using to call the REST API?

Comment: http://localhost/cashtocode/wp-json/api/pay/transactions/<transaction_id>

Comment: @Ericvadim The above code is correct and working fine.